# Storyboard Auto Reverse in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation, storyboard, windows-phone

I have a button which animates the controls(basically, moving an object) using the storyboard.
But If i click the button the second time the animation should do the reversal and come back to its initial position. We have a auto-reverse property in storyboard, but that fires soon after the animation gets completed. But i want to reverse it, after the user input. Is there any shortcuts to do this or just to position it again with the storyboard. Let me know if i am not clear on the scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42093/Silverlight-Creating-a-simple-smooth-reverse-story